# Abstracting a global variable to a property?

Tags: javascript, properties, global-variables, abstraction

I'm reading DOM Scripting and have a beginner question about the abstraction below. The original code didn't include "clearTimeout", and "movement" was declared as a global variable. While the code ran fine, it wasn't a smooth animation which is why clearTimeout was added. My question however, is why I can't just test for "movement" and when it fails (on the first mouseover call to moveElement) continue on through the rest of the function? If I keep "movement" as a global variable, rather than make it a property, the code doesn't run at all?

If it helps to see the other JS and HTML, I've plugged the remaining code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMcA/7NES8/).

```
function moveElement(elementID,final_x,final_y,interval) {
  if (!document.getElementById) return false;
  if (!document.getElementById(elementID)) return false;
  var elem = document.getElementById(elementID);
  if (elem.movement) { //Why can't I use "movement"?
    clearTimeout(elem.movement);
  }
  var xpos = parseInt(elem.style.left);
  var ypos = parseInt(elem.style.top);

  if (xpos == final_x && ypos == final_y) {
    return true;
  }
  if (xpos < final_x) {
    xpos++;
  }
  if (xpos > final_x) {
    xpos--;
  }
  if (ypos < final_y) {
    ypos++;
  }
  if (ypos > final_y) {
    ypos--;
  }
  elem.style.left = xpos + "px";
  elem.style.top = ypos + "px";
  var repeat = "moveElement('"+elementID+"',"+final_x+","+final_y+","+interval+")";
  elem.movement = setTimeout(repeat,interval); //Originally global property
}​
```

Comment: Please show us the non-working code. Having `movement` as a global variable outside the function should work (as long as you only animate one element)

Comment: Never ever pass strings to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). Please, pass a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A property can never be `undefined`, only have a `undefined` as a value. In contrast, a variable may be `undefined` (not defined) or have `undefined` as a value.

When you say `if (movement)`, in the case that `movement` is not defined, it will throw an exception.

When you say `if (elem.movement)`, in teh case that `elem.movement` is not defined, it will evaluate to false and fail the condition without exceptions.

If you want to use `movement` as a global variable, you must first *declare* it before attempting to read from it via:

```
var movement;
function moveElement(elementID,final_x,final_y,interval) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could try to read the global `movement` as a property, since all global variables are just properties of the `window` object (in a browser):

```
if (window.movement) { // this will never throw an exception
    clearTimeout(movement);
}
```

And finally, you could switch your if statement to one that protects itself against these exceptions via the `typeof` operator:

```
if (typeof movement !== 'undefined') {
    clearTimeout(movement);
}
```

Comment: I think you answered my question. I assumed without "movement" defined it would just evaluate to false. But that's where I'm wrong, it throws an exception which is why the remaining code doesn't run? Am I following your answer correctly?

Comment: And if yes, is this just an exception that comes built into JS?

Comment: The remaining code does not run because an exception interrupts the interpreter from continuing to parse any javascript - an unhandled exception in javascript (almost always) means the show is over. [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mCUx/1/) may help clear things up.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to fully understand. Thank you.